# "Unrecognizer selector sent to class" on class category after importing framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linker, categories, unrecognized-selector

After adding MessageUI.framework to my Xcode (4.3.2) iOS project I get:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '+[Message responseArrayKey]: **unrecognized selector sent to class ..**

for one of my class extensions.

Message class is simply NSManagedObject subclass and I have category NSManagedObject(Synchronize) on it:

```
     //
    //  Message.h
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

    #import "NSManagedObject+Synchronize.h"
    @class Message;



       @interface Message : NSManagedObject {
        @private
            }
        ...
    @end
    //
    //  NSManagedObject+Synchronize.h

    @interface NSManagedObject (Synchronize)
    +(NSString *)responseArrayKey;
    @end
```

To be clear: The code worked before and I have Linker flags set to: -Obj-C and -all_load. (Followed: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html)

Somehow thou - this framework breaks the linking. What is so special in this framework? I am using many more framework and none of them is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have repaired the issue by refactoring my Message class to CDMesage. Looks like there was class name clash with MessageUI framework.